# spring data paging with start and end counts

Tags: java, mongodb, paging, spring-data, scroll-paging

I'm using **spring data with mongodb** and have issue which is described below.

```
Pageable pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, count);
return projectRepository.findAllByUserId(userId, pageRequest);
```

from the frontend part i'm getting start and end values for returning a page result but unfortunately i can't get the page number because i use scrollable loading not a pager. and seems spring data allows only make a pageRequest with these 2 parameters, ***page number*** and ***data count***.

Is there a way to pass only **start** and **end**  of the data and return a page result instead with spring data?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you scroll you might be fetching a fixed number of records? Each scroll event should help you track the page numbe, and the count can be the number of records you pull afresh.

Hope that helps.

Comment: most probably yes it should be fixed somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the same size each time you can calculate the page numbers as start / size. 
Example:
start: 70, size: 10, page = (70/10) 7
But it is 0-based by default, so your actual page number is 6